# Who is this character from Avatar : The Last Airbender?

Tags: avatar-the-last-airbender, character-identification

[image: Unindentified Avatar character]

I know this is from Avatar but I don't know who this character is...

Comment: A resident of Kyoshi Island and the biggest fan of the Avatar. He is in quite A few episodes, where, in all he shows devotion to the Avatar. Often known as 'The foamy mouth guy' this islander is the most mysterious character by far (My opinion for the last part)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

According to the Avatar Wiki

> The [foaming mouth guy](http://avatar.wikia.com/wiki/Foaming_mouth_guy) was a resident of Kyoshi Island and possibly the
>   biggest fan of the Avatar.

He appears in two episodes of Avatar, "The Warriors of Kyoshi" and "Avatar Day".

---

He doesn't appear to have a name but he does get a mention on the (now defunct) [Official NickToons Avatar webpage](http://kr.turbonick.nick.com/shows/avatar/index.jhtml)

[image]

Comment: An excellent example of the humor that made the series so fantastic.

Comment: The creators also stated at Comic-Con 2006 that Suki once dated FMG. She does not consider it one of her prouder moments.